# Horizontal scrolling in shiny.fluent DetailsList (R shiny app with Microsoft Fluent UI)

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, fluent

In a Shiny application, I would like to display a table with a lot of columns using `DetailsList` from the `shiny.fluent` R package. I am struggling: How can I add an horizontal scroll bar ?

Here is the code for a minimal example. At this stage, only a small subset of the columns are visible. How can I allow horizontal scrolling? Maybe a `JS` solution?

```
library(shiny)
library(shiny.fluent)
library(glue)

makeCard <- function(title, content, size = 12, style = "") {
  div(
    class = glue("card ms-depth-8 ms-sm{size} ms-xl{size}"),
    style = style,
    Stack(
      tokens = list(childrenGap = 5),
      Text(variant = "large", title, block = TRUE),
      content
    )
  )
}
ui <- fluentPage(
  tags$style(".card { padding: 28px; margin-bottom: 28px; }"),
  uiOutput("analysis")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$analysis <- renderUI({
    Stack(
      tokens = list(childrenGap = 10), horizontal = TRUE,
      makeCard("Top results", div(style="max-height: 500px; overflow: auto", 
      DetailsList(items = cbind(cbind(fluentSalesDeals,fluentSalesDeals), fluentSalesDeals))))
    )
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I am quite new to `shiny.fluent`, maybe another Fluent component would be more appropriate?

NB: I know that I can always fall back on `renderDataTable` (or any other of this kind) but I'd like to discover new UI components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide `columns` to your `DetailsList` the horizontal scroll bar is properly added. However, in the default setting it is only visible if you scroll down to the end of the table. To remedy this, you can add `constrainMode = 0`.

*N.B.* I rendered only one version of `fluentSalesDeals` instead of 3 for the sake of  simplicity.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shiny.fluent)
library(glue)
library(tibble)

makeCard <- function(title, content, size = 12, style = "") {
   div(
      class = glue("card ms-depth-8 ms-sm{size} ms-xl{size}"),
      style = style,
      Stack(
         tokens = list(childrenGap = 5),
         Text(variant = "large", title, block = TRUE),
         content
      )
   )
}
ui <- fluentPage(
   tags$style(".card { padding: 28px; margin-bottom: 28px; }"),
   uiOutput("analysis")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
   output$analysis <- renderUI({
      div(
         class = "ms-Grid", dir = "ltr", 
         div(class = "ms-Grid-row",
             div(class = "ms-Grid-col ms-sm11",
                 Stack(
                    tokens = list(childrenGap = 10), horizontal = TRUE,
                    makeCard("Top results", 
                             div(style="max-height: 300px; overflow: auto", 
                                 DetailsList(items = fluentSalesDeals,
                                             columns = tibble(fieldName = names(fluentSalesDeals),
                                                              name = names(fluentSalesDeals))
                                             #, constrainMode = 1 ## default
                                 )
                             )
                    )
                 )
             )
         ),
         div(class = "ms-Grid-row",
             div(class = "ms-Grid-col ms-sm11",
                 Stack(
                    tokens = list(childrenGap = 10), horizontal = TRUE,
                    makeCard("Top results", 
                             div(style="max-height: 300px; overflow: auto", 
                                 DetailsList(items = fluentSalesDeals,
                                             columns = tibble(fieldName = names(fluentSalesDeals),
                                                              name = names(fluentSalesDeals)),
                                             constrainMode = 0
                                 )
                             )
                    )
                 )
             )
         )
      )
   })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Fluent User Interface with two tables. The table on the bottom shows a horizontal scroll bar.]